# SquarePOS - Why isn't the sale appearing on dashboard ?

Tags: square, square-connect

I'm trying to generate a sale from a HTTP POST request using the [SquarePOS API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-createorder)

This is the request I fire in Postman

```
curl -X POST \
  https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/*****/orders \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ******' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: ******' \
  -d '{
  "idempotency_key": "123456AZD",
  "reference_id": "my-order-006",
  "line_items": [
    {
      "name": "Américain - Article de base",
      "quantity": "1",
      "base_price_money": {
        "amount": 1599,
        "currency": "EUR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "taxes": [

  ],
  "discounts": [

  ]
}'
```

The server answers with

```
{
    "order": {
        "id": "DQYutFAsu5hB8Xr56zBdmiilxd4F",
        "location_id": "N7VH9XRBT57MP",
        "line_items": [
            {
                "quantity": "1",
                "name": "Américain - Article de base",
                "base_price_money": {
                    "amount": 1599,
                    "currency": "EUR"
                },
                "gross_sales_money": {
                    "amount": 1599,
                    "currency": "EUR"
                },
                "total_tax_money": {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "currency": "EUR"
                },
                "total_discount_money": {
                    "amount": 0,
                    "currency": "EUR"
                },
                "total_money": {
                    "amount": 1599,
                    "currency": "EUR"
                }
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2018-04-30T12:44:47.816Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-30T12:44:47.816Z",
        "status": "OPEN",
        "reference_id": "my-order-006",
        "total_tax_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "total_discount_money": {
            "amount": 0,
            "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "total_money": {
            "amount": 1599,
            "currency": "EUR"
        }
    }
}
```

Which seems to say that the order has been successfully created. However, when browsing the SquarePOS dashboard, I don't see the sale appearing in the sales list.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing when creating the order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is being created correctly, but I think you are missing something. The [Orders API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/orders-api-overview) lets you create an order that you can then charge with the Charge endpoint.You cannot create an order via the APIs at this time and have them show up in the Dashboard or Point of Sale without charging them.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Is this possible to charge with cash for example ?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is the creation of an order in the dashboard without having to rely on the POS owner nor the client. The point is just to have a record that an item has been sold

Comment: At this time it is not possible to record an order without actually charging a card.

Comment: Mmmh, too bad .. Thanks for the help though !